# Forge Design Automation AutoCAD engine version 23.1 works, but 24 and 24.1 do not recognize custom command

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-designautomation

My company has been using Autodesk Forge to parse DWG files, and I recently saw that Activity/App Bundle creation was failing due to a deprecated Engine version (I was previously using `Autodesk.AutoCAD+22`).

So, I'm trying to switch to using `Autodesk.AutoCAD+24_1` engine as that is the latest version available as listed [here](https://aps.autodesk.com/en/docs/design-automation/v3/developers_guide/engine-lifecycle/).

However, after creating a new Activity and App Bundle using this new engine version, my work items keep failing with the following log in the returned report: `Unknown command [name of my command].  Press F1 for help.`

I have not changed anything, just the engine version. I noticed version 23.1 is being deprecated today, so I figured I'd try that out, and I see that it works as expected! So I'm wondering if there's anything wrong / needs to be enabled for version 24.1 (also tested 24, which has the same issue).

This is concerning because today is the last day for version 23.1 before deprecation, and starting tomorrow we won't be able to deploy any new changes using a later version.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Big thanks to Madhukar from Autodesk for assisting me over email. Turns out what I was missing was specifying the command name within PackageContents.xml. Below is an example of how such file should look like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ApplicationPackage
  SchemaVersion="1.0"
  AppVersion="1.0.0.0"
  Author="company"
  Name="ExampleCommand"
  Description="Example">
    <CompanyDetails Name="company" />
     <Components>
    <RuntimeRequirements OS="Win64" Platform="AutoCAD"/>
    <ComponentEntry AppName="ExampleCommand" ModuleName="./Contents/ExampleCommand.dll" AppDescription="Blah" LoadOnCommandInvocation="True" LoadOnAutoCADStartup="True">
      <Commands>
        <Command Global="ExampleCommandName" Local="ExampleCommandName"/>
      </Commands>
    </ComponentEntry>
  </Components>
</ApplicationPackage>
```

The part I was missing and which fixed my issue was (where `ExampleCommandName` is the name of the custom command defined in your DLL):

```
<Commands>
    <Command Global="ExampleCommandName" Local="ExampleCommandName"/>
</Commands>
```

I'm not sure why omitting that worked for Autodesk.AutoCAD+22, but looks like it's definitely needed for newer engine versions.

Answer (score 0):

> I have not changed anything, just the engine version

I think that's the problem. You must rebuild appbundle so that it is compatible with the new engine version.

Comment: I'm not sure what I need to change in the app bundle code - I don't make any engine specific configurations within my code. I'm already referencing the 24.1 AutoCAD DLLs (I had mistakenly assumed AutoCAD2022 = R22, which is why i was using a deprecated engine version before), which is the only AutoCAD-version-specific thing I can think of in the AppBundle code

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you might not have updated SeriesMin and SeriesMax in packagecontents.xml when you change Engine version.
Go to your app bundle, edit PackageContents.xml, find `RuntimeRequirements` and update the `SeriesMin` and `SeriesMax`

```
<Components>
  <!--Madhu:You need to set SeriesMax to Engine version which is R24.2-->
    <RuntimeRequirements 
      OS="Win64" 
      Platform="AutoCAD" 
      SeriesMin="R24.0" 
      SeriesMax="R24.2"/>
    <ComponentEntry
      AppName="HelloCommands"
      ModuleName="./Contents/Hello.dll"
      AppType=".Net"
      AppDescription="Hello World"
      LoadOnCommandInvocation="True"
      LoadOnAutoCADStartup="True">
    <Commands GroupName="ComandosVB">
      <Command Global="Hello" Local="Hello" />
    </Commands>
    </ComponentEntry>
  </Components>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I was not aware of the SeriesMin/Max fields. I tried it, but still get the same FAILED_INSTRUCTIONS work item status, with the unknown command message. I tried using engine version 23.1, and this still works (not sure how since it should've been deprecated yesterday). If I add SeriesMin="R23.0" and SeriesMax="R23.1", using engine version 23.1 works. If I change SeriesMin="R24.0" and SeriesMax="R24.2" (still using engine version=23.1), then I get the "unknown command" error as expected. But for some reason, switching to 24 or 24.1 doesn't work even with these fields.

Comment: Is there anything I need to change in the actual source code/dependencies for the DLL I compile for my custom command? I was already using AutoCAD2022 (v24.1) before, so I believe it should be using the correct version of the AutoCAD dependency DLLs

Comment: Please share your bundle at aps.help@autodesk.com

Comment: Please note that we only disallow new `activity`/`appbundle` creation of the deprecated engines. The `workitems` on the activity referencing to the deprecated engines still work until the engine is removed. For Autodesk.AutoCAD.23_1 Engine removal date is March 28, 2025.

Comment: Right, I am able to create new versions of activity/appbundles today using version R23.1, which I believe should've been deprecated according to the deprecation policy. I have sent an email to that help address you mentioned with a minimal example to reproduce. Thanks

Comment: I haven't recieved anything ... Can you please tell the ticket number, you should recieve an email like this.

Your request (12456) has been received and is being reviewed by our support staff.

To add additional comments, reply to this email.

Comment: Right, `23.1` is deprecated on `March 29, 2023`, but we still allow one more day to indeed disallow the creation of create new versions of activity/appbundles. I don't think a new activity/appbundle referencing `23.1` can be created now. Please let us know if you still can. :)

Comment: Thanks Emma, yes I now see the deprecation message, good to know there is a one day buffer. Madhukar was able to assist me via the aps.help@autodesk.com process, I'll add a new answer explaining what my issue was.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar kind of problem occuring....

I already have a model checking app running on design automation that uses the AutoCAD+24_1 engine and it runs without a problem.

I then had to update my app so that instead of running the code on the current open drawing, it would load a drawing into a side/external database, and then run the checks on the side/external database.

When i tested those changes, the app works fine on my machine within Civil 2022 (v24.1), and its built using the 2022 version of the API DLLs

But when loaded onto DesignAutomation, I get the same "Unknown Command" error that you do. I should see a message output to the command line when the app initializes, but i dont see that, so something is stopping the app from loading

My feeling is that there is something now in my app that design automation doesnt like, and causes it to crash when it tries to load it in.
In my case, its something that i have recently coded in. In your case, it might something that was already coded in that previous engines were happy with, but 24_1 isnt. What it is, i have no clue, but it might be a pointer towards the reason why its not loading.